# Problem with recurring contributions on PayPal sandbox

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, recurring-contributions

I am setting up a CiviCRM website and using one of its modules to try to set up a recurring payment using PayPal.  From the CiviCRM website, I get taken to the first PayPay screen:

[image]

I click on "Pay using debit or credit card" and get to this screen:

[image]

I fill this in with some dummy details, and click "Continue".  At this point, my browser says "waiting for www.sandbox.paypal.com" and never returns.

I have tried this on a number of occassions, at different times of day, but always the same result.

I did wondering if it was hanging at the point of sending an IPN back to my website, but PayPal does not list any IPN attempts.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I create an account on the Paypal Sandbox server and then create a sub-account on that which has a bank account, balance, etc. And then when I test via the sandbox, I log into that sub-account and "pay" via it. I've never tried creating an account once I get sent over there to pay. Maybe that is the issue. But since it's stuck over at Paypal, this sounds more like a Paypal issue?

Comment: Hi.  I tried using a PayPal account and it worked, so the issue must be with the PayPal sandbox, which is a bit pants

Comment: Did you set up both a Paypal Sandbox account and then create at least one subaccount on there where you gave it a bank account, balance, and/or card (all fake, of course)? I've always had that part done first before then testing my site via sandbox. I use it all the time to test our emails and such as we change the formatting and text.

Comment: I was trying to test the case where the customer does not have and does not want a PayPal account, so they just enter their card details.  In this use-case, I get the issue with PayPal not responding.  However, the use-case where the customer uses an existing PayPal account does work

Comment: Yea, I think it's one of the things that doesn't work in Paypal Sandbox.